# Will my CSS render correctly across Android's WebView and IOS UIWebView?

Tags: android, ios, css, webview, uiwebview

I am working on a mobile application project which sometimes require me to display some HTML/CSS content within the app. The app is coded as native programs in IOS as well as Android. Now I know I can use `Webview` in android and `UIWebView` in IOS to display my web stuff, but my question is, will the HTML/CSS content be displayed exactly the same in both devices? Or will CSS differ in rendering as it often does in different web browsers? Are there any common pitfalls, or known inconsistencies? Any help will be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking yes. Both browsers will display html/css correctly, but certainly there are little differences.

I recomend you K.I.S.S: Keep It Simple Stupid.
Simple Layout prevents missbehaviour.

But you can check [this](http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/15-techniques-and-tools-for-cross-browser-css-coding), is a non-exhaustive collection of cross-browser css coding

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for your timely response and the link provided. Can you please be more specific about "certainly there are little differences"?

Comment: can YOU be more specific? css is more about browser than operative system. Most browsers follow the most basic css lineups, but  -webkit-gradient will work only on safari and  -moz-linear-gradient only on firefox. What you want to accomplish? Have you tryed anything yet? If you don't try anything you will never succeed. Maybe you're just panicking about everything that can go wrong.. and most of times nothing goes wrong